# Anyone knows how to plot this ascii data?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need to plot this ascii data, but I don't know how because I tried several times and always had a problem with the size of the data, basacally, these is the data:

```
0.462e+00 0.934e+00 0.173e+01 0.285e+01 0.424e+01 0.568e+01 0.693e+01 0.779e+01 0.819e+01 0.821e+01
 0.794e+01 0.744e+01 0.674e+01 0.589e+01 0.498e+01 0.410e+01 0.334e+01 0.271e+01 0.220e+01 0.181e+01
 0.152e+01 0.129e+01 0.111e+01 0.972e+00 0.857e+00 0.764e+00 0.686e+00 0.614e+00 0.532e+00 0.419e+00
 0.259e+00 0.414e-01 -0.232e+00 -0.550e+00 -0.894e+00 -0.123e+01 -0.151e+01 -0.168e+01 -0.173e+01 -0.164e+01 
-0.148e+01 -0.135e+01 -0.137e+01 -0.166e+01 -0.227e+01 -0.323e+01 -0.450e+01 -0.600e+01 -0.753e+01 -0.882e+01
-0.968e+01 -0.998e+01 -0.973e+01 -0.899e+01 -0.790e+01 -0.660e+01 -0.528e+01 -0.407e+01 -0.305e+01 -0.223e+01
-0.162e+01 -0.118e+01 -0.882e+00 -0.692e+00 -0.578e+00 -0.513e+00 -0.481e+00 -0.479e+00 -0.505e+00 -0.552e+00
-0.611e+00 -0.667e+00 -0.709e+00 -0.724e+00 -0.706e+00 -0.648e+00 -0.553e+00 -0.434e+00 -0.302e+00 -0.166e+00
-0.271e-01 0.112e+00 0.245e+00 0.363e+00 0.457e+00 0.523e+00 0.562e+00 0.581e+00 0.587e+00 0.589e+00
 0.596e+00 0.613e+00 0.645e+00 0.688e+00 0.737e+00 0.780e+00 0.808e+00 0.816e+00 0.803e+00 0.771e+00
 0.725e+00 0.671e+00 0.616e+00 0.567e+00 0.526e+00 0.496e+00 0.476e+00 0.464e+00 0.460e+00 0.463e+00
 0.471e+00 0.485e+00 0.503e+00 0.524e+00 0.546e+00 0.564e+00 0.576e+00 0.579e+00 0.575e+00 0.564e+00
 0.549e+00 0.529e+00 0.508e+00 0.487e+00 0.466e+00 0.446e+00 0.427e+00 0.409e+00 0.393e+00 0.381e+00
 0.373e+00 0.370e+00 0.373e+00 0.383e+00 0.400e+00 0.422e+00 0.449e+00 0.478e+00 0.503e+00 0.519e+00
 0.525e+00 0.520e+00 0.506e+00 0.486e+00 0.463e+00 0.439e+00 0.418e+00 0.400e+00 0.385e+00 0.372e+00
 0.361e+00 0.350e+00 0.339e+00 0.328e+00 0.316e+00 0.306e+00 0.295e+00 0.285e+00 0.276e+00 0.268e+00
 0.260e+00 0.253e+00 0.247e+00 0.241e+00 0.236e+00 0.232e+00 0.229e+00 0.226e+00 0.224e+00 0.222e+00
 0.220e+00 0.218e+00 0.215e+00 0.212e+00 0.209e+00 0.204e+00 0.198e+00 0.192e+00 0.185e+00 0.178e+00
 0.171e+00 0.164e+00 0.158e+00 0.152e+00 0.147e+00 0.142e+00 0.137e+00 0.133e+00 0.128e+00 0.124e+00
 0.119e+00 0.114e+00 0.110e+00 0.105e+00 0.101e+00 0.958e-01 0.912e-01 0.865e-01 0.817e-01 0.769e-01
 0.721e-01 0.671e-01 0.620e-01 0.569e-01 0.518e-01 0.470e-01 0.425e-01 0.384e-01 0.346e-01 0.313e-01
 0.282e-01 0.253e-01 0.225e-01 0.197e-01 0.168e-01 0.139e-01 0.109e-01 0.779e-02 0.468e-02 0.153e-02
-0.163e-02 -0.481e-02 -0.801e-02 -0.112e-01 -0.145e-01 -0.178e-01 -0.212e-01 -0.245e-01 -0.277e-01 -0.307e-01
-0.334e-01 -0.359e-01 -0.381e-01 -0.402e-01 -0.421e-01 -0.439e-01 -0.456e-01 -0.474e-01 -0.492e-01 -0.509e-01
-0.527e-01 -0.545e-01 -0.562e-01 -0.579e-01 -0.595e-01 -0.611e-01 -0.626e-01 -0.641e-01 -0.655e-01 -0.669e-01
-0.682e-01 -0.695e-01 -0.707e-01 -0.718e-01 -0.729e-01 -0.740e-01 -0.750e-01 -0.759e-01 -0.768e-01 -0.776e-01
-0.784e-01 -0.791e-01 -0.797e-01 -0.804e-01 -0.809e-01 -0.814e-01 -0.819e-01 -0.823e-01 -0.827e-01 -0.830e-01
-0.833e-01 -0.835e-01 -0.837e-01 -0.838e-01 -0.839e-01 -0.839e-01 -0.839e-01 -0.839e-01 -0.838e-01 -0.836e-01
-0.835e-01 -0.833e-01 -0.830e-01 -0.827e-01 -0.824e-01 -0.820e-01 -0.816e-01 -0.812e-01 -0.807e-01 -0.802e-01
-0.796e-01 -0.791e-01 -0.785e-01 -0.778e-01 -0.772e-01 -0.765e-01 -0.757e-01 -0.750e-01 -0.742e-01 -0.734e-01
-0.726e-01 -0.717e-01 -0.708e-01 -0.699e-01 -0.690e-01 -0.680e-01 -0.671e-01 -0.661e-01 -0.651e-01 -0.641e-01
-0.630e-01 -0.620e-01 -0.609e-01 -0.598e-01 -0.587e-01 -0.576e-01 -0.564e-01 -0.553e-01 -0.541e-01 -0.530e-01
-0.518e-01 -0.506e-01 -0.494e-01 -0.482e-01 -0.470e-01 -0.458e-01 -0.446e-01 -0.434e-01 -0.422e-01 -0.409e-01
-0.397e-01 -0.385e-01 -0.372e-01 -0.360e-01 -0.348e-01 -0.335e-01 -0.323e-01 -0.310e-01 -0.298e-01 -0.286e-01
-0.274e-01 -0.261e-01 -0.249e-01 -0.237e-01 -0.225e-01 -0.213e-01 -0.201e-01 -0.190e-01 -0.178e-01 -0.166e-01
-0.155e-01 -0.143e-01 -0.132e-01 -0.121e-01 -0.110e-01 -0.991e-02 -0.883e-02 -0.776e-02 -0.671e-02 -0.568e-02
-0.465e-02 -0.365e-02 -0.265e-02 -0.168e-02 -0.716e-03 0.226e-03 0.116e-02 0.207e-02 0.296e-02 0.384e-02
 0.469e-02 0.553e-02 0.635e-02 0.715e-02 0.793e-02 0.869e-02 0.943e-02 0.101e-01 0.108e-01 0.115e-01
 0.122e-01 0.128e-01 0.134e-01 0.140e-01 0.146e-01 0.151e-01 0.157e-01 0.162e-01 0.167e-01 0.171e-01
 0.176e-01 0.180e-01 0.184e-01 0.187e-01 0.191e-01 0.194e-01 0.197e-01 0.200e-01 0.203e-01 0.205e-01
 0.207e-01 0.209e-01 0.211e-01 0.212e-01 0.213e-01 0.215e-01 0.215e-01 0.216e-01 0.216e-01 0.216e-01
 0.216e-01 0.216e-01 0.215e-01 0.215e-01 0.214e-01 0.213e-01 0.211e-01 0.210e-01 0.208e-01 0.206e-01
 0.204e-01 0.202e-01 0.199e-01 0.196e-01 0.193e-01 0.190e-01 0.187e-01 0.184e-01 0.180e-01 0.176e-01
 0.172e-01 0.168e-01 0.164e-01 0.160e-01 0.155e-01 0.150e-01 0.146e-01 0.141e-01 0.136e-01 0.130e-01
 0.125e-01 0.120e-01 0.114e-01 0.109e-01 0.103e-01 0.970e-02 0.911e-02 0.852e-02 0.792e-02 0.731e-02
 0.670e-02 0.607e-02 0.545e-02 0.483e-02 0.420e-02 0.357e-02 0.292e-02 0.227e-02 0.166e-02 0.112e-02
 0.590e-03
```

This is data from an earthquake amplitude in ascci values

Comment: how are those ascii values? they're floats and there's only one axis, not a function and x-axis or function and y-axis

Comment: They are only y-axis values, all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the ascii numbers to float and plot them:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datastr = datastr.replace('\n', ' ')
points = list(map(float, datastr.split()))
print(points)
plt.plot(points)
plt.show()
```

Comment: 'datastr' belongs to any module of pyhton?

Comment: @DIEGOAXELVALENCIATORRES could it be the code block of your question

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 1
----> 1 datastr = datastr.replace('\n', ' ')
      2 points = list(map(float, datastr.split('CMB_2.txt')))
      3 print(points)

NameError: name 'datastr' is not defined

Comment: @DIEGOAXELVALENCIATORRES define the variable `datastr` with the content of the number text block in what ever way you want